# to give some chance reader

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I am reading Maugham,

> Heaven knows what pains the author has been at, what bitter experiences he has endured and what heartache suffered, **to give some chance reader a few hours' relaxation** or to while away the tedium of a journey.

Why did he write in this sequence? Can you paraphrase this line so it reads more natural? as it doesn’t read comfortable to me.

Comment: Have you looked up 'chance' (adjective' in a dictionary? The line you quoted is good English.

Comment: hhh alright, I thought too much.

Answer (score 1):

A reader is a reader by chance, almost by accident, by throw of the dice. They may have seen the book on a bookstall shelf and bought it because they liked the cover, or the title, or the dust-jacket précis. The author's efforts are often unrelated to the circumstances by which a reader may acquire the result of their endeavours.

There is reason authors such as Maugham are still read, long after their passing; that of being able to carve beauty from the very bedrock of the language, to evoke entire plot and sub-plot in a mere sentence.
Writers of lesser calibre may find that, rather than achieve such worthy heights, instead they can only attain at best a rather [purple prose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose).